# CodeIgniter não cadastra

Tags: array, codeigniter, sql-insert

Estou tentar inserir uns dados no banco mas não consigo. Algum problema no array que o CodeIgniter retorna.

Segue o Controller que o formulário chama:

```
    function cadastrar()
{
    $this->load->helper('array');

    $dados = array();
    $dados2 = array();

    $dados2 = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

    $this->load->model('Entidade_model', '', TRUE);

    if($this->Entidade_model->cadastrar($dados2))
    {
            $dados['tp_msg'] = 'success';
            $dados['msg'] = '<strong>Warning!</strong> Entidade inserida com sucesso!';
    }
    else{
            $dados['tp_msg'] = 'danger';
            $dados['msg'] = '<strong>Warning!</strong> Erro ao inserir entidade.';
    }

    $this->load->view('alert', $dados);
}
```

Segue o Model que o Controler manda os dados:

```
    function cadastrar(array $data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('entidade', $data);
}
```

E ele não cadastra.

Comment: E qual seria esse problema no array?

Comment: seria interessante saber o retorno tambem

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte, cara.
Primeiro, te aconselho a ler o guia de usuário do CodeIgniter, especialmente essa [parte](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html)!
Segundo, quando eu criei o meu cadastro eu segui a regra que está nesse guia, então eu preenchi o array só no model e utilizando o array associativo dessa forma:

> $data = array(
>           'titulo' => $this->input->post('titulo')
>       );